# Implementing Scrolling progress bar for more than one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, progress-bar

I'm trying to implement the scrolling progress bar. (The bar that'll tell the user about How much of an article within an `div` (s)he has read).

Something like implemented on [this](http://www.webdesigncrowd.com/demo/scrolling-progress-bar-6.23.14/?scid=social29424356) site.

I've Designed my custom bar and coded it on [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/Vedant_Terkar/kzx0z831/1/). It works fine you can see it.

Here is code:

HTML:

```
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="xyz">
    Hello !!<br />
    XYZ<br />
    Hello !!<br />
    XYZ<br />
    Hello !!<br />
    XYZ<br />
    Hello !!<br />
    XYZ<br />
    Hello !!<br />
    XYZ<br />
    Hello !!<br />
    XYZ<br />
    Hello !!<br />
    XYZ<br />
    Hello !!<br />
    XYZ<br />
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="xyzprog"><div id="prog">Intro</div></div>
```

JQuery/JS:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var elemTop=$("#xyz").offset().top,elemHeight=$("#xyz").height();
        var total=elemTop+elemHeight;
        var scTop=$(window).scrollTop();
            var prog=((scTop-elemTop)/elemHeight)*100;
        var html="Intro;Read=";
            if(prog>100){ prog=100; html="Intro;Read=" }
        if(prog<0){ prog=0; }
            $("#prog").animate({
                "width":""+prog+"%"
            },1).html(html+""+prog+"%");

    });
});
```

CSS is irrelevant so not posting it.

Now what I want is:

- Is there any way to make this code work for more than one element (say 10 minimum)?
- Can anyone design a plugin that will work like say `$(elem).scrollProgress()` and how? I'm really eager to design one but don't know how to start :(.
- Is there any better way to do it?

Any advice, idea, thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already some plugins doing what you want. Check out [toc-scrolling-progress](https://github.com/jfitzsimmons2/toc-scrolling-progress).

But if you want it on the whole page you could do something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var documentHeight = $(document).height();
  var windowHeight   = $(window).height();
  var distanceToTop  = $(window).scrollTop();

  var percentScrolled = distanceToTop/(documentHeight - windowHeight) * 100;
  $('#progress-bar').css({'width': percentScrolled + '%'});
});
```

I created a jsfiddle with a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdmznqds/)

Comment: That plugin is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks, +1. But I need to develop an plugin. can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: You should check out the jquery doc on plugin creation => http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/